# .htaccess remove extension while preserving uri parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

i was trying to rewrite my urls in a friendly way; i have written all the php code to handle everything.
The only thing that i am unable do is removing the .php extension while preserving the uri parameter.
So, essentially, i'm looking for some .htaccess rules to change from this:

    `www.example.com/biography.php/john-doe`

to this:

    `www.example.com/biography/john-doe`

(john-doe isn't a real file, it's only the GET parameter passed to biography.php)

Thanks everyone.

Comment: ok, i give up. The 2 answers didn't worked for some reason (404 error for both). This seems to work: `RewriteRule ^biography/(.*) biography.php/$1 [L]` . It's ugly but works. Thanks anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Should do:

```
RewriteRule ([^\.]).php(.*) $1$2 [QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the links on your site are already like this

> www.example.com/biography/john-doe

and you want to process them on the server like this

> www.example.com/biography.php/john-doe

add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z]+)/([-a-zA-Z]+)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```